# ClassNotFound:apache.hadoop.io.ImmutableBytesWritable Integrating Spark with Hbase using Python

Tags: java, python, hadoop, apache-spark, hbase

I am trying to integrate Spark and Hbase and use it through python and keep on getting error related to ClassNotFound. (line 77 -83) Here is the code that I am using: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/hbase_inputformat.py#L70

Error that it gives me is :[image]

I am new to java. I am not sure about the directory structure of java classes due to which i am unable to navigate to the folder where I can find all these classes. Anyway, can someone tell me how can i get the org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableByteWritable?

Comment: how do you submit your application? I suppose you use spark-submit, look for option '--jars' and pass the path to hbase-client.jar corresponding to your hbase version

Comment: I am using pyspark and starting python spark driver =  ipython for setting up everything. I am running the commands in ipython shell.

Comment: Yeah, take a look at `--jars` option then. If you have some problems with that, take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-5185. But first try to do sth like `bin/pyspark --jars /path/to/hbase-client.jar ...`

Comment: do you have any suggestion on how to find this hbase-client.jar?

Answer (score 0):

This file is part of HBase.

Make sure that you have included this dependency ( Jar , Maven Dependency ) within your project.

You can perform mvn dependency:tree and make sure that you have included this dependency.